# Dropbox not installed properly on 1204

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, dropbox

I have tried to install Dropbox, here is my situation now:

1) I start my laptop and them a popup appears where I have to enter my sudo-password such that Dropbox can run as Superuser.

2) I enter the password, after which the terminal starts downloading Dropbox. When reaching 100%, it stalls completely.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Download the right dropbox version.
- Open a terminal (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type: `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Restart your machine.

After the restart you can see a dropbox icon click on it and this will download additional files. You will *then* asked to login details.

If this doesn't work, leave a comment.

Comment: Good answer.  Please review the [edit]s I've made to make your next answers even better!  The original OP will (*should*) let you know whether this worked or not!